# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a small MVC app that I use for practice reasons, but now I am encountering an error every time I try to debug:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I've googled but cannot find a solution. I'm using .NET 4.5.

It can't be the DLL file because I'm using .Net 4.5.

Comment: see dependency here .. https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work... Instead i get an error on Package Manager saying 'NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand'

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Whenever I have a NuGet error such as these I usually take these steps:

1. Go to the packages folder in the Windows Explorer and delete it.
2. Open Visual Studio and Go to *Tools* > *Library Package Manager* > *Package Manager Settings* and under the Package Manager item on the left hand side there is a "Clear Package Cache" button. Click this button and make sure that the check box for "Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build" is checked.
3. Clean the solution
4. Then right click the solution in the Solution Explorer and enable NuGet Package Restore
5. Build the solution
6. Restart Visual Studio

Taking all of these steps almost always restores all the packages and dll's I need for my MVC program.

---

**EDIT >>>**

For Visual Studio 2013 and above, step 2) should read:

2. Open Visual Studio and go to *Tools* > *Options* > *NuGet Package Manager* and on the right hand side there is a "Clear Package Cache button". Click this button and make sure that the check boxes for "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" are checked.

Comment: One should also make sure to remove older versions of updated libraries from source control.

Comment: @Jordan_Walters Great answer - this helped me to solve my problem as well.  However, I feel that you could improve (and quite possibly gain more rep) by describing the rationale behind the procedure.

Comment: Good advice but it didn't fix my issue with "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the path specified".  For me I had to go to Tools /  NuGet Package Manager / Package Manager Console and then "Update-Package -ProjectName MyProject -reinstall".  Everything fixed!

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy I think it's in ${SolutionDir}/packages/ . I.e. the root solution folder.

Comment: Great tips, thanks, they really helped me. I hope you don't mind that I added some further information to reflect later versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Following these instructions, I received the error "The imported project "\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.3.2\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found.  Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694/the-imported-project-c-microsoft-csharp-targets-was-not-found and am currently SOL

Comment: I followed the above and yet the error stayed - i manually looked at the dll version and when i checked my web.config file there were duplicate entries, just leave a single entry to match your dll version and everything should work - it did for me

Comment: Thanks @JazziJeff I just had the wrong version in my web.config

Comment: I would only add that in my case, I had to reopen the solution as a final step. VS2017

Comment: Sadly this created more problems.  Packages that were fine now can't be found, GenerateDepsFile task failing....

Answer (score 200):

- Remove all code references to `System.Net.*`
- in the package window,

  `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`
- Clean and rebuild your project

Comment: I just ran into this problem and I installed the latest NuGet package version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client and then I saw System.Net.Http.Formatting in my references list.

Comment: I tried everything else.  This is the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me.  Make sure you install the right version.

Comment: This solution worked after I updated my `Web.Config` `bindingRedirect` for  `System.Net.Http.Formatting` and `System.Web.Http` to the new one installed by the above command... ie it went from `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>` to `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.30319" newVersion="4.0.30319"/>`

Comment: Is it the case then that many of us were simply missing the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client NuGet package?

Answer (score 29):

I found an extra

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.28.0" newVersion="2.2.28.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

in my web.config. removed that to get it to work. some other package I installed, and then removed caused the issue.

Comment: how do you know what the public token is of the version ?

b03f5f7f11d50a3a

Comment: Its added automatically by the package manager console command: Add-BindingRedirect *

Comment: I did the same and it worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 24):

user3919888 pointed me in the right direction, but I needed to run `Update-Package -reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` in the Package-Manager console. Basic install by itself does not recognize the problem but does recognize that the package is already installed and does not overwrite it.

I'm posting this answer because this happens so infrequently that I end up googling and reaching this page before I remember what I did last time.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Removing the following lines from `web.config` solved my problem. Note that in this project I didn't use WebApi components. So for others this solution may not work as expected.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: how do you know what the public token is of the version ?

Comment: As I know it is public token of all Microsoft dlls regardless of their version.

Comment: To be funny I added these lines and it helped.

Comment: That fixed the problem for me too.

Comment: This solved my problem as well. I had converted an old Web Site project to a Web Application. The Web.config file was referencing version 5.2.7, while the installed NuGet package was 5.2.3. Deleting this from the Web.config fixed the error.

Answer (score 14):

For those that use **.NET Standard** project in combination with **.NET Framework** projects:

In the .NET Standard way, packages that are included in a .NET Standard project will correctly be used across other .NET Core and .NET Standard projects.

Im the .NET Framework way, if you are referring to a .NET Standard project from an .NET Framework (MVC) project, you need to manually download and install the same nuget packages.

So the answer to my question was that I had to download and install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` in the web project (.NET Framework) that is using a .NET Standard project where `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` is needed. In fact, I already had this installed but there was a version difference.

I just add this answer for others to see, it might not directly answer OP's question but it did save me time by first checking this instead of doing the top-voted answers.

Comment: I am using .NET Core and found a guide to mock the HttpClient on https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/. Following that guide gave me the problem described in OP's question. And you solution fixed the issue :)

Comment: This is what worked for me. Tried the recommended approach, removing and restoring all packages, but in the end I had to use Nuget to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client making sure it is the version I needed and all was good after that,

Comment: Great answer - I was starting to think I'd need to move everything back to the Framework!

Answer (score 7):

As originally suggested in a comment by [GeoMac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090431/geomac) and documented on [NuGet's docs](http://blog.nuget.org/20121231/a-quick-tutorial-on-update-package-command.html) the following worked for me when none of the other answers worked:

Tools / NuGet Package Manager / Package Manager Console

```
Update-Package -ProjectName MyProjectName -reinstall
```

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2015. This is what I had to do, fixed it instantly.

Answer (score 6):

1. Remove all code references to `System.Net.*`
2. Uninstall: Package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` and its dependencies.
3. Reinstall all: Package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` and its dependencies.
4. Clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Thank you! You saved me after 2 days of desperate tries. It almost made me crazy.

Answer (score 4):

For me this issue was caused by having a missing assembly binding entry in Web.config (System.Net.Http.Formatting) after adding the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package.

I checked the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client version I had, and added the following binding to the Web.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Depending on the WebApi.Client version you have, change the version in the binding redirect.

Comment: This sorted it for me. I tried all of the above, uninstalling/reinstalling various packages, but it was just missing the additional few lines in `web.config`¬

Answer (score 3):

In my case none of the above solutions worked.  I solved by right clicking on the reference

> System.Net.Http.Formatting

from Visual studio and setting the property **Copy Local** to **true**.

I hope this is useful somehow.

Comment: i did that and it still happens

Answer (score 2):

For me it was as simple as

1. Delete `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` from the packages folder in Windows Explorer
2. Open Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console
3. Click the "Restore" button

Comment: I had to update it to a newer version, but might have been the reinstall that did it and not the version bump.

Answer (score 2):

What solved this annoying error for me was just to close Visual Studio and open it again. Then rebuild the solution, and it all worked again. Sorry for the crap answer, but I think it's worth an answer because it solved it for me.

Comment: This was all it took for me too

Comment: Not "crap" when it's this quick and easy to try!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem because

> System.Net.Http.Formatting

version written inside webconfig was 5.0.3 but inside the bin folder the library System.Net.Http.Formatting dll version was 4.0.2

so I just replaced with the same given inside bin

[image]

[image]

just do this clean project and build

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the above worked, however, replacing 5.2.3.0 with 4.0.0.0 did solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve this problem is

1. Go to NuGet package manager.
2. Select Updates (from the left panel)
3. Update WebApi components
4. After that, the project ran without errors.

Answer (score 1):

VS2019: Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Setting -> in Package Restore section, check 2 options.
After that, go to project packages folder and delete all child folders inside (for no longer any error)
Then Rebuild solution, Nuget will redownload all packages and project should run without any reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with a ASP.NET project in VS 2019.

Another symptom was, that some references (System.Web.Http) were marked as faulty in the project references list (Solution Explorer)

**My solution:**

1. Delete the faulty references in Project -> References (right click, ...)
2. Build
3. Navigate to the build errors "The type or namespace name [...] could not be found" or similar
4. Use the "Show potential fixes" -> Install package

**The cause:**

Looking at the difference in the csproj file I could see the **reason for the trouble.** Someone managed to reference a DLL in the Windows Program file folder!

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set library reference as "Copy Local = True" on properties dialog. On visual studio click on "references" then right-click on the missing reference, from the context menu click properties, you should see copy local setting.

Answer (score 0):

For Me adding few below line in WebApi.config works as after updating the new nuget package did not works out

```
var setting = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
setting.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
setting.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

Don't forget to add namespace:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization; 
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Comment: please make sure to check the project dependency by right click on solution file and then under common properties->project dependencies check the project where the error is thrown or check the project name on which solution is dependent

Answer (score 0):

**Check your version matches both --> web.config file and
--> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client,Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi if not pls update accourdingly**

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to consider. When using .NET 5.0 apps (like blazor WASM) in a .NET 4.x solution, you may be adding conflicting files. Additionally, if you have installed Microsoft .NET SDK 6 or 7, it does not matter your target framework (such as 5.0). **dotnet publish** will always use the most recent version of the SDK. This can lead to unexpected problems because you now have incompatible dlls or even dlls you don't need. Try creating a global.json file to indicate the SDK you want to use during publish.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your answers,
I too faced the same System.Net.dll error and scratching my head for 2 days , tried all your inputs but no use and the user Taha sultan who referred about the bin folder, got an idea to check my bin folder in the particular project

1.I checked my bin folder(showed an red * mark that System.Net.dll
was ignored) under the particular project in the solution explorer
as well as in the project folder in the system/laptop and found
that the particular dll system.Net.dll is not available in the bin
folder so I copied the same dll from the project root folder and
pasted in the bin folder.

```
2.Clean the solution
3.Build the solution
4.Closed the solution
5.Reopened the solution and ran the application Hurray it got run .
```

All the very best to all