# The new DLL Hell; wrong assembly version being bound

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, json.net, nuget

I'm running VS2013 update 1 with Nuget v 2.8.50313.46

You can skip to **this is the important bit**, and some recent updates, and come back for reference.

I have a VS solution, this is a simplified representation of it.

```
-- Solution
    - Base (Class Library)
        Packages:
            No Packages Installed.
        References:
            System
            System.Configuration
            System.Core
            System.Runtime.Caching
            System.Web

    - AppBase (Class Library)
        Packages:
            No Packages Installed.
        References:
            System
            System.Core
            System.Web.Http
            Base

    - Client (Console Application)
        Packages:
            EntityFramework                v6.1.0
            HtmlAgilityPack                v1.4.6
        References:
            EntityFramework
            EntityFramework.SqlServer
            HtmlAgilityPack
            System
            System.Core
            AppBase
            Base

    - Server (Web Application)
        Packages:
            HtmlAgilityPack                v1.4.6
            Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi        v5.1.2
            Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client v5.1.2
                (dependent on > Newtonsoft.Json v4.5.0)
            Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Web... v5.1.2
            Newtonsoft.Json                v6.0.3
        References:
            HtmlAgilityPack
            Newtonsoft.Json
            System
            System.Net.Http
            System.Net.Http.Formatting
            System.Web
            System.Web.Http
            System.Web.HttpHost
            AppBase
            Base
```

The code inside the `Server` needs `Newtonsoft.Json v6.0.3` to function.

When I rebuild all and run everything works fine, as expected.

I subsequently build just `AppBase`, without building `Server`. `AppBase` is dependent only on `Base`.
The binaries for `AppBase` and `Base` are "up-to-date", as expected.

However,

**this is the important bit**,

the building of `AppBase` causes the `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` in the "Server\bin" folder to be substituted for the earlier 4.5 version.

When I make a request to the `Server`, a "500 Intrernal Server Error" is returned due to the binding error caused by the incorrect `Newtonsoft.Json` dll version.

Why does building an assembly effect a non dependent assembly?

Has anybody else experienced this?

What is the best way to resolve this problem?

---

**EDIT** 19/06/2014

I made a new solution file, at first I thought this had resolved the problem.
However the problem had transferred to the `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` :-S

If I edit `AppBase` so it does not reference `System.Web.Http` the effect goes away.
Maybe this is something to do with the MVC stuff in Program Files? ...

---

**EDIT** 20/06/2014

I've posted a [community wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24324248/659190) that details how I've worked around the problem. I thought somebody might find it useful. However, the workaround doesn't explain what mechanism is effecting `Server` when I build only `AppBase` and `Base`. Does this sound like a bug, it seems wrong?

Comment: So you are saying that without building `Server`, it does replace some dependent assemblies in it's `bin` folder? I didn't quite understand your question.

Comment: Have you tried an assembly redirect binding to the latest version? That's what I did when I ran into a similar issue, and it worked fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet: That was my proposed solution too, but I didn't quite get whether I understood the question correctly (whether that answered the question).

Comment: @PatrickHofman, that is exactly what I'm saying, unlikely as it sounds.

Comment: How do you build the code? Do you have a separate configuration for the build?

Comment: This sounds like a post-build step or something, building a project shouldn't replace DLLs in dependent projects.

Comment: @PatrickHofman the active solution configuration is Debug and every project is included.

Comment: @HighCore I don't think it's related to NuGet. One of the DLLs you 'add like a man' could be relying on older version of Json.NET.

Comment: @Jodrell: And if you disable that? Does it still occur?

Comment: If have that issue too ... VS is copying the v4.5 DLL from the Blend subdirectory of Visual Studio. Don't know why yet ...

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this problem in a new solution, doing the same set-up?

Comment: @Gene I've tryed renaming the DLL in the Blend folder, restarting IIS and Visual Studio but it doesn't help, I'm not sure where the older version is being copied from. I have my packages in an offline repository and the system is disconnected from the internet so its not being pulled in remotely.

Comment: I'm currently making a new solution file ..

Comment: @Jodrell I marked the DLL read-only to see where VS fetched the file from (happend to me with SignalR in a OWIN console app).

Comment: I have most definitely experienced this too but I don't have a good solution.

Comment: You got a .nuget/nuget.config file in your solution root?  Does it include a `<packageSources>` *add* element pointing to your local repository?

Comment: Also, I'd set a read-only on that json dll to quickly try to see what is overwriting it.  If that doesn't throw an error, (ew) process monitor.

Comment: @Will, I have no `nuget.config` file. I tried the read-only, see my work-around in answers.

Comment: @Gene, I tried the read-only thing see my work around in answers.

Comment: @Stijn, yes, I could recreate the problem with a new solution, see my work around in answers.

Comment: I hope my edit is OK; When I first read over the question, I was a bit confused, given the order you had the updates. I *think* this is a bit easier for someone coming across this first to understand and realize their problem is/is not related, for example.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but are you using NuGet package restore?  If you are, and combined with the changes in NuGet 2.8 to [-DependencyVersion Switch](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.8), that may go some way to explaining the odd Server/bin writes.  My theory being when you build AppBase, something odd is happening in MSBuild (check your targets) that's triggering something via the NuGet config refs... pure guesswork though!

Comment: @SteveChapman I am using auto package restore.

Comment: @Jodrell - This might seem like an odd question, but do you use Git?

Comment: @SirJuice, yes, I do use Git.

Comment: @Jodrell - Please check to see whether your .gitignore file explicitly excludes .dll files from source control.  Also make sure that your .gitignore is under version control.  If not, it might be possible that someone else on your team is submitting outdated .dll files which might overwrite yours.  I have also found that an incorrect Git setup can cause havoc with your Nuget package files.

Comment: Is there any chance that other .csproj is referencing another version of the Json dll? Search for references with "HintPath" in the .csproj and you can see if some of your projects are picking up the dll from other place.

Comment: @EricLemes, sorry, what do you mean by "other". **Server** references 6.0.3 of Newtonsoft.Json, **AppBase** doesn't reference it at all.

Comment: I meant Base, AppBase, Server and Client. Now I see that my idea doesn't make any sense. Sorry.

Comment: I have had the same issue as well, it seemed to start when I upgraded from ASP.NET MVC 3 to 5.  In my case, I get an old version of System.Web.Mvc copied into my web app bin folders, even though there are NO (direct) references to anything but MVC 5.2 in my solution.  I also see it happen when I build project trees that do not include the affected web application project.

Comment: Anybody found a solution for this issue since the problem was posted? I am also struggling with this issue in past few days. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

The reference to `System.Web.Http` in `AppBase` was pointing to

> C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Http.dll

I added my latest

> ```
> Microsoft.AspNet.WepApi.Core   5.1.2
> ```

package to `AppBase` as used in `Server`. This pulled in the dependency packages,

> ```
> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.1.2
> Newtonsoft.Json                6.0.3 (the only version in my package source)
> ```

The `System.Web.Http` reference in `AppBase` now points to,

> *MySolutionFolder*\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.1.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll

When I build `AppBase` now, the WepApi DLLs in `Server` no longer get altered to legacy versions.

---

Incidentally,

This package change adds multiple `(a|A)pp.config` files within the solution's projects, all with binding redirects to the latest version of `Newtonsoft.Json`.

---

**Note**

I actually view this as a work around albeit, one I'm glad to find.

The code in `AppBase` does not actually need the latest `System.Web.Http.dll`.
I still don't know why building `AppBase` should effect `Server`, is this a bug?

Marking the troublesome DLLs as read-only did not protect them. Changing the security rights did, but no error was logged during the build of `AppBase`, even with diagnostic build logging.

Comment: Won't this be overwritten when the package gets updated?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, I think so yes, but since both `AppBase` and `Server` use the package it should happen in line. I suspect that if `Newtonsoft.Json 4.5` was available in my repository, I might still have problems because WepApi has a dependency on the older version. I could work around that by explicitly pulling the  6.0.3 version into `AppBase`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman this still doesn't explain why building `AppBase` should effect `Server` (I don't think it should.)

Comment: I know. I had like to know the answer myself too.

Answer (score 1):

Nuget installs the selected package and any other packages it is dependent on. 
Obviously, in your Server solution there are packages using Newtonsoft.Json v4.5, so Nuget copies the dll to the bin, there is the problem occurs.

You may use [binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as Jon Skeet commented, or you should stick using Newtonsoft.Json v4.5 in Server solution.

Another option is using [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) to reference two different versions of this dll.

Comment: There's no 4.5 package in the solution (and doesn't need to, because 6.0.3 satisfies the dependency for >= 4.5). VS is copying the file from somewhere else into the output folder.

Comment: So when, I build `AppBase` and `Base` ONLY, does Nuget copy some packages into the `Server` bin folder?

Comment: If so, will Nuget examine binding redirects and negotiate to the highest possible version?

Comment: @Gene: It is difficult to tell are there references on Newtonsoft.Json 4.5 packages without examining solutions Base.csproj, AppBase.csproj and Server.csproj. I'd look for Reference Include nodes and corresponding HintPath.

Comment: @Jodrell: I wasn't technically correct by saying "Nuget copies", because Nuget adds appropriate references to the package folder to the project. When project files contain references to dlls in the packages folder the VS can build and copy locally these assemblies. It is CLR job to resolve binding redirects. Nuget won't manage references to two versions of same assembly, and I think it's problematic to do in VS as well (not sure if Aliases property can help?).

Comment: @Jodrell: Nuget will use (non-technically speaking) the "least common denominator" version of the referenced assembly assuming that it has backward compatibility. So, yes, it will negotiate to the highest possible version in some sense. 

If I were in your situation I would examine Base.csproj, AppBase.csproj to see if there are discrepancies in references. But if there were discrepancies those projects wouldn't load, IMO. My guess is the answer is specific to your case.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem you are experiencing relates to the package cache of your solution.

Try the procedure, as described in Jordan Walter's answer, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403650/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-formatting-or-one-of-its-depen)

Comment: This wasn't it but, the packages folder has caused other issues we've had. The packages folder is now in our `.gitignore`. The problem in the question would reoccur, even after deleting the packages folder an auto-restoring.

Comment: @Jodrell OK, I hear you.  What is the impact of that when adding new Nuget packages on Computer A, committing, and then pulling from Computer B?  Do you now need to manually add the Nuget Package on Computer B as well?  Do you need to enable Nuget to download missing packages during build?

Comment: Each projects `packages.config` is under source control so, we do share what packages each project uses. The only impact is, when you pull the solution clean from Git, the package cache, in the `<solution>\Packages` folder is not there. So, when you do the first build all the packages are downloaded from the package source. If you are using Continuous Integration and `MSBuild` you have to add a pre-build step that uses `NuGet.exe` to do this.