# Umbraco gets error on dev server

Tags: web-config, umbraco7

I just published my local version to a dev server. My local is working perfectly, but the dev has an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Does anybody know how can I fix it?

I started to use VS 2015, because of nuget version. Now I got some different error in the output box:

```
 No way to resolve conflict between "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "5.0.0.0" [] to Version "5.2.3.0" [F:\Projects\frs\frs\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [] to Version "2.0.0.0" [F:\Projects\frs\frs\bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "3.0.0.0" [] to Version "4.0.0.0" [F:\Projects\frs\frs\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
```

Comment: Are you sure the dev server has the same .NET Framework as your local machine? Have all the .dlls been pushed to dev?

Comment: Yes, same version and I copied all files.

Comment: Weird. Is the IIS application (app pool) on local and dev set to use the same framework? Is IIS the same version both places? Is there a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting in the web.config and if so, have you tried removing it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think there isn't any reference, but I need to check in the evening.

Comment: I checked, the local is 4.5, the server is 4.5.2. Is that still ok?

Comment: Not sure. Have you tried Arlans suggestion?

Comment: I tried before a different suggestion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403650/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-formatting-or-one-of-its-depen). Now I have more error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/53820-Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-SystemNetHttp-after-upgrade-to-v-621

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
```

to this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Umbraco. I have installed Umbraco v7.4.3 and I tried the Ucalendar Package in it.
You have to remove the Package and restore the `app_data` and `config` folders.