# Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0...."

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

We have a shared project on TFS. Everyone is able to load the project without issue. In my case, one particular reference, `System.Net.Http.Formatting`, has a yellow triangle and an exclamation mark.  The Path in Properties show blank.  My other colleagues have it as C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll.

I checked my PC and it has a file with the same name but with extension .xml in the same folder.  There is no dll file.  Why isn't my project loading properly? Where is the configuration for this reference located? How can I update it manually?

---

Added in response to first comment:

The .csproj file contains the following line in the <ItemGroup> block:

> <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />

---

According to the registry, I have .NET Framework 4.6.2 on Windows 10 Anniversary Update:

[image]

How do I get the file System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll properly installed in its correct place?

Comment: Check that the project infact has a reference to System.Net.Http-assembly.

Comment: Your project seems to be using a Nuget-package System.Net.Http.Formatting (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/) which might be missing. Check Nuget-package manager that the package is installed and up to date. Also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403650/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-formatting-or-one-of-its-depen

Comment: I made a mistake in my original post.  The `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` file does not exist.  Only the xml file is there.  How can I install the dll file?

Comment: Have you checked the nuget-packages of the project? The dll will be downloaded via nuget.

Comment: If I use Nuget, won't my solution will be out of step with all the other people who is also working on this solution. If I check it in, all the others will be affected. If I don't check it in, then I won't be able to get changes made by others.

Comment: I see this inconsistency happening as well. Some dev machines have dlls and some instead just have xml files "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies"